# Cannot Install PEAR folder inside PHP version 5.3

Tags: php, iis-7, smtp, pear

I have an IIS7 server installed as Remote where I have installed php, everything is working fine but inside my php folder PEAR folder is not present, because of that I cannot receive a mail through smtp, Also after doing lot of googling which said to install pear i require gp-pear.php file which is not available inside my php folder, now how can I install Pear in my IIS7 server?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the installation instructions as they are listed in the PEAR manual:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

Comment: I installed pear by putting go-pear.phar file in my php folder in IIS7 server but still mail is not sent. I dont think there is any source code error since mail is sent from my local system where xampp is installed but when file is uploaded on remote IIS server , mail is not sent

Comment: you do not install pear by putting a file somewhere. read the instructions fully.

Comment: I put go-pear.phar inside my php folder and in my terminal, cmd i rum the command c:/>program files x86/php/>php go-pear.phar and installed pear in IIS through several steps same as given in this url http://ruslany.net/2010/11/how-to-install-php-pear-and-phploc-on-windows/ and please if you cannot help do not write these kind of comments I do have common sense that putting a file inside a folder pear cannot be installed